# understanding Dagger 2 app Architecture

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm trying to get my head around Dagger 2 and Dependency Injection. I figured a good way of doing it was to take a look at the official [Coffee example](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee). I also read through the official documentation on the github page, but I found it rather confusing for newcommers .

As you can see in the image below, I stripped down all the classes and colored them to understand what's going on. But I still have some doubts

[image: Coffee Classes]

My questions:

1) I've heard that we use DI because passing the dependencies on the constructor makes our code verbose. Well, the amount of code and classes on this example enormously exceeds what it would have taken to just supply these two parameters in a constructor. Furthermore, the code would be much more human friendly. What is the advantage of doing it this way?

2) **PumpModule** declares a provider that takes the thing it is supposed to provide as a parameter... that is a tad counter intuitive. What's really going on there?

3) I really got lost here (CoffeApp.java)

```
DaggerCoffeApp_Coffe.builder().build()
```

What is that doing? Where's DaggerCoffeApp_Coffe? Android studio says it can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer 1**

> "the amount of code and classes on this example enormously exceeds
>   what it would have taken to just supply these two parameters in a
>   constructor"

In an example code or a very small app  - yes. In a normal sized or big app you will have hunders if not thousands of times to provide "these two parameters in a constructor".

One of the best advantages of the DI is that it allows (and to some extend maybe forces) you to create modular apps, where the modules can be developed and **tested** in isolation. This may not sound as a big deal but again, when the app grows bigger it becomes really hard to add new changes without breaking things. When you develop a module you can isolate yourself from the rest of the app by defining interfaces that provide the needed functionality and define `@Inject`s for these interfaces. That way if you later (months, next version?) decide that you need to change/extend/rewrite some module other modules will not be affected as long as you don't change it's interface. You will be able to write your replacing module and then just 'switch' to it in your `@Provides` method.

The other big advantage of DI is that it allows you easily to feed mock objects into your unit tests. For example: let's say you have an `Activity` that uses GPS location provider to detect the location. If you want to test it without DI you will have to run your app in the emulator in debug mode, provide manually some "fake" locations and at some breakpoint inspect if the activity is in the expected state. With DI you can easily feed mock location provider into your `Activity` that simulates GPS location updates with some predefined by you values. Of course you may again run your app manually in the emulator (or real device) but you can also run it automatically as part of the unit tests or even in the continuous integration server process like Jenkins. That way each time you change your code you can run the tests and immediately see if the changes broke something. The other value is that automatic tests save **your** time. In the example probably you will need at least 2 minutes for the manual test. Automatic test will take seconds and more important it will run without the need of your attention/input while running.

For more info I recommend this great video by Jake Wharton:
https://www.parleys.com/tutorial/5471cdd1e4b065ebcfa1d557/

Here the slides for the video:
https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2-devoxx-2014

**Answer 2**

> "PumpModule declares a provider that takes the thing it is supposed to
>   provide as a parameter"

That provider provides the **interface**, not the concrete class. That is the whole point. When you migrate your app to DI you have to create an interface for each class that you want injected. As explained in in Answer 1, that way you will be able to easily replace the concrete implementation with mock object for the testing or with new better implementation for the later versions of the app.
For example: at some point you decide that you need Rotary Vane Pump instead of `Thermosiphon`. You write your `RotaryVanePump` class and then simply change your method to `@Provides Pump providePump(RotaryVanePump pump) {`.

How this works ((over)simplified explanation):

1. DI graph it built by `DaggerCoffeApp_Coffe.builder().build()` (please see Answer 3 first)
2. At some point Dagger finds in your code `@Inject Pump mMyPump`;
3. Dagger sees that you need Pump injected and seeks in the DI graph how to provide it.
4. It finds the `@Provides Pump providePump()` method. Dagger sees that it requires `RotaryVanePump` object.
5. Dagger seeks the DI graph how to provide `RotaryVanePump`.
6. There is no `provide` method in any module but `RotaryVanePump` does not need one because it has parameterless constructor so Dagger can instantiate an object.
7. New object is instantiated of type `RotaryVanePump`
8. Dagger feeds this object in `providePump()` as actual parameter.
9. `providePump()` returns with that object as return value.
10. `RotaryVanePump` is injected into the `@Inject Pump mMyPump` field.

And all this is done automatically, you don't have to care about it.

**Answer 3**

`DaggerCoffeApp_Coffe` is generated by Dagger. You will have to use this in order Android studio to "see" the generated classes.
https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt

> "What is that doing?

That is doing the whole magic :-). It builds the dependency graph and checks **at compile time** that all dependencies are satisfied. That "at compile time" differentiates Dagger from all other DI frameworks which are unable to validate the graph at compile time and if you miss to define some dependency you will get an ugly runtime error.

In order all of your `@Inject`s to work you will have to first build the graph using call like this.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear and straightforward explanation!

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I've been reading a lot of tutorials without success.  Could you explain why PompModule just returns that parameter as it's given to it?. How does it know how to create a Thermosiphon in the first place. it needs to inject a Heatet!. The modules seem to be defined the other way around. I mean, the object that NEEDS dependnecies is the module being added as a dependency on DripCoffeModule. It really confuses me a lot

Comment: 'CoffeMaker' needs `Heater` and `Pump` injected. `Heater` is provided by `DripCoffeeModule` which creates it in the "normal" way: `new EllectricHeater()`.
`Pump` is provided by `PumpModule`. It provides it using `providePump()` method. When using `provide*` method you have 2 choices: 1. either create it as in `provideHeater()` using the normal way with `new`, or 2. declare the dependency as parameter. When dagger finds your provider method (in this case `providePump()`) it "sees" that it needs `Thermosiphon` and injects it (and also injecting all the needed objects that Thermosphon needs).